# Remove blue border on hit area

Tags: html, css, focus

I'm trying to work out how to remove the blue border on this accordion hit areas. I'm sure its a quick fix but for the life of me can't work it out where to cancel it out.

**Live example**
http://bradfrost.github.com/this-is-responsive/patterns/fluid-accordion.html

You'll notice clicking on the headers makes the blue focus box to appear around it.

Answer (score 2):

You need `outline:none` for the header boxes. However some people recommend not to do it [for accessibility reasons](http://outlinenone.com/)